# Binary depending on the sign of another variable

Tags: optimization, linear-programming, integer-programming

I'm writing a mixed integer linear problem, where I have an indicator function in the objective function counting the instances of negative values of a decision variable. I thought of defining a binary variable that takes the value of 1 when the decision variable, say x, is negative and 0 otherwise. But I couldn't come up with a constraint that would ensure this relation. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: With $y$ the binary variable, and $M$ a sufficiently large constant value:
$My \ge -x$, $M(1-y) \ge x$